# Simple single user revision control

Tags: version-control, synchronization

I work alone on various small projects. I work in different places and on different machines (at home, at work), so I have to synchronize source code between them.

Currently I just work on different directories (for versions) and email myself zips (for syncing the work done at home with the work done in other places).

How can I improve my workflow with some version-control or sync tool?

Comment: @Daniel, just approved your edit. Please read the note by Lancelot, he's actually right about tag usage: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8967272

Comment: @NickVolynkin Okay - im only adding git and svn when questions dont specify which they want to use, and when at least one of the 2 is already present (so people arnt put off) - but i see your point. Still at least one more out there with it (done maybe 15+ edits in last few min) but ill keep in mind for future :)

Comment: @DanielB: Also I've noticed that you've been removing the [tag:source-code] from multiple questions. I agree that it should be removed. But the edited questions usually don't get better from it, most of them are closed anyway. Since your edits are small,  reviewers may get mad about them and reject with "no improvement whatsoever " or raise a moderator attention flag. This can result in temporary edit ban. So, a friendly advice — don't make like 100 such edits in a single day. Once you hit 2000 rep, you'll be able to make unreviewed edits. Then you can purge the whole 300+ usages at once. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin - okay... Meta actually asked for people to help kill it off, and linked to those - but i guess they just meant mods... Thought i was helping :(

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, you are helping.  Please join the chat, I'll try to explain details. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84540/edits-that-only-remove-unnecessary-tag

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a server you'd have access to from everywhere? If so, just put subversion on there. Or use github or something similar. Pretty much any version control system which can talk between different machines over the net should be fine, IMO.

I don't think I'd call Subversion "overkill" - it's pretty simple, easy to run, and there are good Windows clients for it.

In terms of hosting, if you're happy for it to be an open source project, then there are any number of places which you could use - [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/), [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), [github](http://github.com), [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) etc.

Answer (score 6):

for this purpose I like using mercurial since it requires no time consuming setups (e.g. svn requires a server somewhere).

Comment: +1 for Mercurial. Subversion is *so* not right for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

[Git](http://git-scm.com) is a fine solution for version control, suitable for scales of project all the way from single user to the Linux kernel (and beyond). I use Git for all my personal projects, and can easily work in multiple places and merge the repositories later.

With the use of a common web-accessible repository like [Github](http://github.com), working in multiple places becomes even easier.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/). I used to use Subversion, but it is tedious, especially if don't have Internet access at all times.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others SVN *does* solve the problem of working in multiple places.  However, like dfa I prefer Mercurial (hg) for this, because then I don't have to choose one master location/server (or do server setup).

Comment: Ja, subversion is truly the CVS of our times.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you one of the distributed version controls out there, like mercurial, git, bazaar, monotone and so on.
working on different folders for different versions is just what their branching is ideal for - you can merge every branch with every branch if you wish to.

just throw an eye upon them.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/). I prefer it over subversion because:

- I don't need a server per-se
- I can have local commits, which is very useful when you're working on several machines

Comment: yes, local commits is a great feature of DVCS

Answer (score 1):

I use a system like [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) to keep my Subversion repositories offsite, and then use TortoiseSVN to keep projects in sync on multiple systems. I also run a full SVN server at home which I keep private paid for projects on. I tend to move between my Mac and my home PC regularly for development and find this the simplest way to keep the files in sync, and at the same time providing and external backup.

Comment: I do the same, but assembla + hg. Originally because I've a few old Sun boxes whose harddrives weren't big enough to put svn on them ( Sun doesn't do a client only package, so you have to install Berkely DB and all sorts of cruft ). The hg client is much leaner.

Answer (score 1):

[SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) is a popular windows-based version control system. Pretty easy to set up, but you do need a windows machine acting as a server.

For single users, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "TortoiseSVN" is a good choice, better than no source control software at all

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Bazaar personally, I've just started using this at home for personal projects and it's really simple to use.

Comment: Yes, bazaar is good, it is very slow though, try mercurial for better speed with equal funcionality

Comment: Also, the name "bazaar" has lame, beardy connotations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Bazaar, and if you don't like a fancy console you can use Bazaar Olive.

I don't know how I got it installed but I also have Tortoise Bazaar, which allows me to work with lower end version control servers :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use something like [sourceforge.net](http://www.sf.net) ?